# How to create safe dispatch function in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to tackle the common warning message in React tests

```
console.error
      Warning: An update to EntryList inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).

      When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):

      act(() => {
        /* fire events that update state */
      });
      /* assert on the output */
```

I have created a hook that can be passed a react dispatcher function

```js
export const useSafeDispatches = (...dispatches) => {
    const mounted = useRef(false);
    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        mounted.current = true;
        return () => (mounted.current = false);
    }, []);

    const safeDispatch = useCallback(
        (dispatch) =>
            (...args) =>
                mounted.current ? dispatch(...args) : void 0,
        // eslint-disable-next-line
        [mounted.current]
    );

    return dispatches.map(safeDispatch);
};
```

and, I am using it like this

```js
function MyComponent() {
   const [counter, d]  = useState(0);
   const [setCounter] = useSafeDispatches(d);
   
   return <button onClick={() => setCounter(counter + 1)}>{counter}<button>

}
```

Yet, I am getting the same error in my tests (where I try to call setState after the component been unmounted)

Comment: If you are having problems with your unit test code then you should probably include your unit test code as part of your [mcve]. The error has to do with how you are testing the component/hook not how the component/hook is implemented. FYI, using "isMounted" checks are also now considered anti-pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this warning because an update has been made to the state of your component after the test is finished.

Search for an async update to the state, and then include an assertion for it in your test.

This warning is the way React is telling you that something happened to your component after the test is finished, and you are not fully testing the component, and you may have missed testing that.

Comment: I know, this Error happens when React try to update a component that been unmounted 
and this why I have this `mounted.current ? dispatch(...args) : void 0,` in my safeDispatches hook

Comment: Would you add a snippet of your actual component and its test ? That would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

In case you just need to get it done right I suggest you to use existing hooks library with appropriate functionality.
For example that [library](https://react-hookz.github.io/web/?path=/docs/state-usesafestate--page) does exactly what you want

```
import { useSafeState } from '@react-hookz/web';

function MyComponent() {
   const [counter, setCounter]  = useSafeState(0);
   
   return <button onClick={() => setCounter((prev) => prev + 1)}>{counter}<button>

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The warning is not due to an unmounted component. It's due to a test finishing before the last state update. Therefor as another comment says use `act` which is designed for that.

Using [waitFor](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/#waitfor) from testing-library which uses act under the hood:

```js
// this test is using testing-library waitFor
test('does something', async() => {
  const { getByRole } = render(<MyCustomButton />);
  await waitFor(() => fireEvent.click(getByRole('button')));
  
  expect(someCallback).toBeCalled(); // or some value to be increased
});
```